# UML Sequence Diagram Implementation

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I have never completed a sequence diagram before and would like to know if my first attempt is correct.

This sequence diagram is to represent someone modifying a pre-existing scoresheet in a tennis game. This change is added to the database.

[image]

Is this a correct way to model this sequence?

**Class Diagram For App**
[image: class diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems

- You confuse who asks and who does : visibly for you the messages 1, 2 and 3 are actions done by the user, but the notation indicates they are done by ModifyScore for 1 and 3, and by Database for 2.
- In your explicit returns (1.2 and 6) you indicate actions, but they can only support the return value(s).
- There is no link between the messages 1, 2 and 3, and the message 2 goes to the Database, and the message 3 has no consequences for the database. That cannot does what you expect.
- It is very difficult to imagine the user asking something to the database

Do you have a simplified version of the Java program you try to describe through the a sequence diagram ?

Comment: Thankyou very much for letting me know, I have added my class diagram for this.

Comment: @JoshBrett in your sequence diagrame you use the classes *ModifyScore* and *Database* but none of them exist in your class diagram

Comment: Possibly, thanks for the help I will re-do the sequence diagrams. Out of curiosity does the class diagram make logical sense/ look good or does that look wrong as well?

Comment: @JoshBrettyou are not novice here so you know you cannot ask for several questios ;-) Just looking very quickly and considering *AwayTeam* and *HomeTeam* you make them inherited by *Team*, but very probably you wanted the reverse. What are the associations between the other classes ? What goal they have ? Ask for an other question for more